# Find a domain within URL with Kusto (Defender ATP Advanced Hunting)

Tags: kql, windows-defender

There's an external list of malicious domains/URL's, and I want to periodically search the logs, but there's an obvious problem:

```
let abuse_domain = (externaldata(sentinel_domain: string )
[@"https://managedsentinel.com/downloads/covid19_domains.txt"]
with (format="txt"))
| where sentinel_domain !startswith "#"
| project sentinel_domain;
abuse_domain
| join 
(
DeviceNetworkEvents
| where Timestamp > ago(1h) 
) on $left.sentinel_domain == $right.RemoteUrl
| project Timestamp,DeviceName,RemoteUrl,DeviceId,ReportId
```

The On clause isn't going to work because the two items will never completely match.  How can I get a match when $left.sentinel_domain is a substring of $rightRemoteUrl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`parse_url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseurlfunction) to extract the domain (`Host`) from RemoteUrl first.

Like so:

```
let abuse_domain = (externaldata(sentinel_domain: string )
[@"https://managedsentinel.com/downloads/covid19_domains.txt"]
with (format="txt"))
| where sentinel_domain !startswith "#"
| project sentinel_domain;
abuse_domain
| join 
(
DeviceNetworkEvents
| where Timestamp > ago(1h)
| extend Host = tostring(parse_url(RemoteUrl).Host)
) on $left.sentinel_domain == $right.Host
| project Timestamp,DeviceName,RemoteUrl,DeviceId,ReportId
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - what's the best way to do that?  It seems clear that I need to extract the url before the join, but if I insert this line:
let parsedurl = tostring(parseurl(abuse_domain).Host)

Comment: Sorry I took too long to edit the above, it should have said:

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - what's the best way to do that?  It seems clear that I need to extract the url before the join, but if I insert this line:

let evildomain = (parseurl(abuse_domain).Host)

It's flagging abuse_domain in that line with "value of type string" expected.  But isn't it a string?  If I try to wrap abuse_domain in tostring, it's "Scalar value expected".

Comment: You have to cast values extracted from a `dynamic` value before they can be used (I think because Kusto can't know at query parse time what the type of the extracted value will be). Try `let evildomain = tostring(parse_url(abuse_domain).Host)`

Comment: When I do that it errors and for abuse_domain it says "A value of string expected".  It's like a weird chicken and egg problem.

Comment: Aha, I see what went wrong now. You're trying to parse `abuse_domain`, but that's a whole table. What you want is to `extend` `DeviceNetworkEvents` _inside_ the join with the host extracted from its `RemoteUrl` column. I've edited my answer with how that should look. Sorry for the slight misdirect.

Comment: You might also want to add `kind=inner` right after the `join` keyword -- the default might not be what you expect. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#join-flavors

Comment: And you might also need to make it `tolower(tostring(parse_url(RemoteUrl).Host))` since joins are case-sensitive